# Order string alphabetically

Tags: c#, .net

I'm reading a .txt file using C #, this file has a list of words, I need to sort the list alphabetically

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(
        @"C:\Users\thoma\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Backup Files\data.txt");

    string orden = "";
    ArrayList arrText = new ArrayList();

    while (orden != null)
    {
        orden = objReader.ReadLine();
        if (orden != null) arrText.Add(orden);
    }
    objReader.Close();

    foreach (string sOutput in arrText)
        Console.WriteLine(sOutput);

    Console.WriteLine("Order alphabetically descendant press 'a': ");
    Console.WriteLine("Ordener ascending alphabetical press 'b': ");

    orden = Console.ReadLine();

    switch (orden)
    {
        case "a":
             string ordenado = new String(orden.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine(ordenado);
            break;
        case "b":
            Console.WriteLine("");
            break;
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This is the code that I have up to this moment. The .txt file shows it without problems but when entering the while statement and press the option, it does not return anything.

In arrText are stored the words of the .txt file, these words are: 'in' 'while' 'are'.

I need that in the while statement when the 'a' key is pressed, show me the list of words but in alphabetical order: 'are'  'in'  'while'.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you expect from `"a".OrderBy(x => x)`... Please doublecheck your code reflects what you think it is doing.

Comment: in the variable sOutput are stored the words of the .txt file, these words are: 'in' 'while' 'are'.
 
I need that in the while statement when the 'a' key is pressed, show me the list of words but in alphabetical order: 'are'  'in'  'while'

Comment: `orden` is a string, so any LINQ on it will work on the letters, i.e. calling OrderBy on a string will sort the letters. As a side node: don’t use ArrayList which is obsolete for more than 10 years now – use the strongly-typed List<T> (here List<string>) class. Or if you want your list to be sorted when you insert items into it use `SortedList<T>`.

Comment: There's no reason to use `ArrayList` anymore, it's obsolete. You can use a `string[]` in this case, and you can also get rid of the streamreader and do: `string[] arrText = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);`

Comment: Thank you very much for the recommendations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should also work with minimal changes to the sample code provided.

First, change ArrayList to `List<string>`

```
List<string> arrText = new List<string>();
```

Second, order using the List OrderBy or OrderByDescending method

```
string ordenado = string.Format("{0}{1}{0}", "'", string.Join("','", arrText.OrderBy(x => x)));
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd offer a slightly better separated and shortened version:

```
    var choices = new Dictionary<ConsoleKey, bool?>()
    {
        { ConsoleKey.D1, true },
        { ConsoleKey.D2, false }
    };

    var ascending = (bool?)null;
    while (ascending == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please choose between ascending and descending order.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for ascending");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 2 for descending");
        var choice = Console.ReadKey(true);
        ascending = choices.ContainsKey(choice.Key) ? choices[choice.Key] : null;
    }

    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("c:/data.txt");
    lines = ascending.Value
        ? lines.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray()
        : lines.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToArray();

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
```

---

Or even this:

```
    var choices = new Dictionary<ConsoleKey, Func<string[], string[]>>()
    {
        { ConsoleKey.D1, xs => xs.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray() },
        { ConsoleKey.D2, xs => xs.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToArray() }
    };

    var ascending = (Func<string[], string[]>)null;
    while (ascending == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please choose between ascending and descending order.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for ascending");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 2 for descending");
        var choice = Console.ReadKey(true);
        ascending = choices.ContainsKey(choice.Key) ? choices[choice.Key] : null;
    }

    var lines = ascending(File.ReadAllLines("c:/data.txt"));

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on your question. Notice that I'm asking about the sort order before you loop the text from the file.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("c:/data.txt");
        var ascending = false;
        var chosen = false;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose between ascending and descending order.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for ascending");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 2 for descending");
            var choice = Console.ReadKey(true);
            switch (choice.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.D1:
                    ascending = true;
                    chosen = true;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D2:
                    ascending = false;
                    chosen = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice");
                    break;
            }
        } while (!chosen);
        var sequence = ascending 
            ? lines.OrderBy(x => x) 
            : lines.OrderByDescending(x => x);
        foreach (var line in sequence)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have an error the name ReadKey does exist in the current context

Comment: @ThomasCaycedoMartinez Should be `Console.ReadKey`.

Comment: @ThomasCaycedoMartinez I added the missing part. I actually wrote it with `using static System.Console;`

Comment: I'd use `bool? ascending = null;` to eliminate the need for `chosen`. Cuts the lines and the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with the original theme of using an ArrayList, the List is much more flexible, but if you must then you need to deal with the limitations of that type.

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\\Temp\\data.txt");
        string orden = "";
        ArrayList arrText = new ArrayList();
        while (orden != null)
        {
            orden = objReader.ReadLine();
            if (orden != null)
                arrText.Add(orden);
        }
        objReader.Close();
        foreach (string sOutput in arrText)
        { Console.WriteLine(sOutput); }
        Console.WriteLine("Order alphabetically descendant press 'a': ");
        Console.WriteLine("Ordener ascending alphabetical press 'b': ");
        orden = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (orden)
        {
            case "a":
                arrText.Sort();
                break;
            case "b":
                arrText.Sort();
                arrText.Reverse();
                break;
        }

        foreach (string sTemp in arrText)
        { Console.Write(sTemp); }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Though, he, and for the matter nobody, should use ArrayList anymore as it’s just obsolete for a long time now.

Comment: I absolutely agree and would up vote your comment if SO allowed such things :)

Comment: Whoops SO does allow for up voting comments, learn something new every day.